# VB .NET Save Panel without form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, panel

In Visual Studio 2008, using VB .NET, I have a Split Container that I want to dynamically load panels into the Panel2 slot from other team member's work based on user input in the Panel1 controls.

Can my team members work on panels outside of a form, save it, then have the main Form just load those panels when needed without copying and pasting each panel into the form and making them visible and invisible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, have the team build user controls which you will then add to the control collection for the panel.